# DateTimePicker updown February missing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `dateTimePicker` created, and I only want to select month and year.  So, I put the following code:

```
dateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = "MM yyyy";
dateTimePicker2.ShowUpDown = true;
```

Whenever I scroll with the arrow through the months, once it gets to February, the value is blank, instead of February.
I also tried `customformats` `MMM` and `MMMM`, but retain the same problem. I tried different years, but every year does not show February. I also tried to put a new `datetimepicker`, but continue having the same problem.

I can only select, without `showUpDown = true`, in the calendar, but still not with arrow up/down.  It works without custom format, but I do not want to see the day, I only want to select month and year.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (10.0.40219.1.SP1). .NET Framework 4.0.30319 SP1.

Comment: Is this for WinForms?

Comment: its in a Windows Form yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user select value by the up-down buttons or arrow keys, the `DateTimePicker` won't change the value of the element which is not included in its custom format.

I guess your `dateTimePicker2` initially has the value of `Now` whose day of month is 29 or 30, hence the error on February.

I recommend you set `1` to `dateTimePicker2.Value.Day` beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem really has to do with the fact that `02/29` will only be valid date on leap years.  To prove this, scroll to `2012` and then scroll to `02`.  You'll have to implement code to catch an invalid value and either notify a user or move to `03/01`.

`DateTime` has a method that lets you find out if a year is a leap year, so that you wouldn't have to jump through hoops: [DateTime.IsLeapYear(year)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.isleapyear(v=vs.110).aspx), where `year` is an `int`.

Here's a short list of leap years for your reference:

```
Leap Years (1800 - 2400)

1804 1808 1812 1816 1820 1824 1828 1832 1836 1840 1844 1848 1852 1856
1860 1864 1868 1872 1876 1880 1884 1888 1892 1896 1904 1908 1912 1916
1920 1924 1928 1932 1936 1940 1944 1948 1952 1956 1960 1964 1968 1972
1976 1980 1984 1988 1992 1996 2000 2004 2008 2012 2016 2020 2024 2028
2032 2036 2040 2044 2048 2052 2056 2060 2064 2068 2072 2076 2080 2084
2088 2092 2096 2104 2108 2112 2116 2120 2124 2128 2132 2136 2140 2144
2148 2152 2156 2160 2164 2168 2172 2176 2180 2184 2188 2192 2196 2204
2208 2212 2216 2220 2224 2228 2232 2236 2240 2244 2248 2252 2256 2260
2264 2268 2272 2276 2280 2284 2288 2292 2296 2304 2308 2312 2316 2320
2324 2328 2332 2336 2340 2344 2348 2352 2356 2360 2364 2368 2372 2376
2380 2384 2388 2392 2396 2400
```

If you think about it, you got really lucky with that bug.  What are the odds that you'll be testing that control on `29`, which is not a valid day for February of this year...  You'll be able to fix it now and not when a user sends a report.